# Webscraping several URLs into panda df

Tags: pandas, web-scraping

Need some help appending several webscraping resaults to a panda df.

Currently im only getting the output from one of the URLs to the DF.

I left out the URLs, if you need them i will supply them to you.

```
##libs

import bs4 
import requests
import re
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
 
##webscraping targets

URLs = ["URL1","URL2","URL3"]

## Get columns

column_list = []

r1 = requests.get(URLs[0])
soup1 = bs(r1.content)
data1 = soup1.find_all('dl', attrs= {"class": "border XSText rightAlignText noMarginTop highlightOnHover thickBorderBottom noTopBorder"})

columns = soup1.find_all('dt')
for col in columns:
  column_list.append(col.text.strip()) # strip() removes extra space from the text   

##Get values

value_list = []

for url in URLs:
  r1 = requests.get(url)
  soup1 = bs(r1.content)
  data1 = soup1.find_all('dl', attrs= {"class": "border XSText rightAlignText noMarginTop highlightOnHover thickBorderBottom noTopBorder"})
  
  values = soup1.find_all('dd')
  for val in values:
    value_list.append(val.text.strip())

  
df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(column_list,value_list)))
df.transpose()
```

Current output only showing the resaults of one URL:

[image]

Expected output:
[image]

Comment: What is the output from `zip(column_list,value_list)`? Can you give the URLs so we can have a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with your `zip` function. It will only zip the values until the length of the shortest list, in this case, the `column_list`. Leaving all the other values unused.

If you want to append the other values to the dataframe as well you will have to iterate over then. So change the last two lines on your code to this and it should work:

```py
result = [[i] for i in column_list]
for i, a in enumerate(value_list):
    result[i % len(column_list)].extend([a])

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
df.transpose()
```

Comment: Hi again. this solved the issue but i dont quiet understand the code. could you please explain more?

Comment: Of course. In the first line we create a nested list called result. Inside this list there are several lists with just one column name. We do this so we can append the other values later. Then in the for loop we use `enumerate` function to get the index and value for each item in `value_list`. Then we append each value to its correspondent column name according to the index.  Now in each list inside the `result` list we have the colum name plus every value you scrapped for this column.

Comment: We use `i % len(column_list)` to get wich column we shall append the current value.